# What semantic notions underlie 'well, pit, shaft' and 'to cut, strike, stamp'?

Tags: etymology

> [pit (n.1)](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=pit&allowed_in_frame=0)
>       "hole, cavity," Old English *pytt* "water hole, well; pit, grave,"
>   from Proto-Germanic *puttjaz "pool, puddle" (source also of Old Frisian pet, Old Saxon putti, Old Norse pyttr, Middle Dutch putte, Dutch put, Old High German pfuzza, German Pfütze "pool, puddle"),
>   early borrowing 
>   from Latin *puteus* **[2.]** "well, pit, shaft," which is perhaps
>   from **[1.]** PIE root [*pau-](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=*pau-&allowed_in_frame=0) (2) "to cut, strike, stamp," but there are phonetic and sense objections, so perhaps a loan-word. Meaning "abode of evil spirits, hell" is attested from early 13c. Pit of the stomach (1650s) is from the slight depression there between the ribs.

Why did linguists impute 2 to 1? [Wiktionnaire](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/puteus#.C3.89tymologie) also asserts this semantic shift.

Comment: Presumably because they sound similar and wells require digging (=striking)...? I'm really not sure what else can be said

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You produce a well or a pit by cutting or striking the ground.
If you read 1 as "hole" and 2 as "dig", the connection should be clear.
It is natural to derive a noun for the result of an action from a corresponding verb.